# Spring security accessing request params and http session within the AccessDecisionVoter

Tags: spring-security

I have a class which implements Spring Security(ver 2.5) `org.springframework.security.vote.AccessDecisionVoter`. The access decision is based around checking the requested article id against a list of id's held in the users http session if the id exists I will return `ACCESS_GRANTED`.

But how do I get hold of the request params and users session info from within the `vote()` method of the `accessDecisionVoter`?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good to know more about your requirements and your configuration, but I would say the the AccessDecisionVoter should get all it needs to make decisions as its parameters:

- Authentication object should contain the GrantedAuthorities
- Object that's being secured should be you article
- ConfigAttributes should pretty much be any additional info used to make the decision

In your case (again, not knowing much about the design of you system), I'd either go for creating something like

```
public class SpecificArticlesGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
  private final Collection<Integer> grantedArticleIds;

  //Constructor

  //Getter for the IDs
}
```

and holding that in your Authentication object.

Alternatively, use a PermissionEvaluator rather than AccessDecisionVoter, which is suited better for ACL-like functionality (but is only available since Spring 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better and more clean way of doing this is to create your own filter (which will have easy access to the request object) that adds the ACCESS_GRANTED GrantedAuthority for that user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any examples that illustrate this?If I add the ACCESS_GRANTED I will need to revoke it at the end of the request. The issue is that the user only has edit rights over the document they initiate.

Comment: Not at the moment. On your comment of revoking the authority, that is perfect for a filter since they "wrap" the request so you could revoke it directly after the call to filterChain.doFilter.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing from `AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>` you're able to get it this way:

```java
public class MyAccessDecisionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        int result = ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

        HttpSession session = null;

        try {
            session = fi.getRequest().getSession(false);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {}

        if (session != null) {
            if (sessionAttributeListContainsArticleID) {
                result = ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```